# How do I check if a column is empty or null in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column in a table which might contain null or empty values. How do I check if a column is empty or null in the rows present in a table?

```
(e.g. null or '' or '  ' or '      ' and ...)
```

Comment: MySQL code: `select isnull(mycolumn) from mytable` returns 1 if mycolumn is null.

Comment: what about  length(trim(mycolumn)) > 0 ?

Comment: For MSSQL > WHERE COLUMN <> '' OR WHERE LEN(COLUMN) > 0 OR WHERE NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(COLUMN)), '') IS NOT NULL

Answer (score 561, accepted):

This will select all rows where `some_col` is `NULL` or `''` (empty string)

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE some_col IS NULL OR some_col = '';
```

Comment: If you change the condition to `WHERE some_col IS NULL OR some_col = ' '` (one space inserted in the string) then it works on both MySQL and Oracle, see answer of "onedaywhen". `some_col = ''` doesn't work on Oracle as empty strings mean NULL there.

Comment: @Johanna but if you switch to `' '`, then it won't work in SQLite. It only handles identical/direct string matching.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE some_col IS NULL OR TRIM(some_col) = '';`
use function TRIM to ged rid of spaces.

Answer (score 163):

As defined by the SQL-92 Standard, when comparing two strings of differing widths, the narrower value is right-padded with spaces to make it is same width as the wider value. Therefore, all string values that consist entirely of spaces (including zero spaces) will be deemed to be equal e.g.

```
'' = ' ' IS TRUE
'' = '  ' IS TRUE
' ' = '  ' IS TRUE
'  ' = '      ' IS TRUE
etc
```

Therefore, this should work regardless of how many spaces make up the `some_col` value:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM T
 WHERE some_col IS NULL 
       OR some_col = ' ';
```

or more succinctly:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM T
 WHERE NULLIF(some_col, ' ') IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks for mentionning the padded spaces. You can profit of them and change the condition to `WHERE some_col IS NULL OR some_col = ' '` (one space inserted in the string) then it works on both MySQL and Oracle. `some_col = ''` doesn't work on Oracle as empty strings mean NULL there and the complete condition becomes NULL.

Comment: My requirement was to find `SELECT * FROM T WHERE some_col IS NOT NULL OR same_col <> ' '; ` and `SELECT * FROM T WHERE NULLIF(some_col, ' ') IS NOT NULL;` worked for me in MySQL. Hope this will be useful.

Comment: Actually `'' = ' '` works in SQLServer but not in SQLite, as far as I can tell, from testing it now.

Answer (score 100):

A shorter way to write the condition:

```
WHERE some_col > ''
```

Since `null > ''` produces `unknown`, this has the effect of filtering out both `null` and empty strings.

Comment: Is there a way of getting the reverse of this, getting all the records where it is NULL or an empty string?

Comment: @JoshPinter: `coalesce(some_col, '') = ''`

Comment: This may have been true sometime, but doesn't work in MySQL 14.14.

Comment: works great and is in fact the only way I could figure out how to filter out both null and empty fields in MariaDB

Comment: I use some_col <> '' to find the reverse of this

Comment: @Chargnn - what did that condition do for `null` values?

Answer (score 41):

*Please mind: the best practice it at the end of the answer.*

---

You can test whether a column is null or is not null using `WHERE col IS NULL` or `WHERE col IS NOT NULL` e.g.

```
SELECT myCol 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE MyCol IS NULL
```

In your example you have various permutations of white space. You can strip white space using `TRIM` and you can use `COALESCE` to default a NULL value (COALESCE will return the first non-null value from the values you suppy.

e.g.

```
SELECT myCol
FROM MyTable
WHERE TRIM(COALESCE(MyCol, '')) = ''
```

This final query will return rows where `MyCol` is null or is any length of whitespace.

If you can avoid it, it's better not to have a function on a column in the WHERE clause as it makes it difficult to use an index. If you simply want to check if a column is null or empty, you may be better off doing this:

```
SELECT myCol
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyCol IS NULL OR MyCol =  ''
```

See [TRIM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) and [IS NULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-null) for more info.

Also [Working with null values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html) from the MySQL docs

Comment: You present the real solution in a very convoluted way.  First you present an incomplete solution to his problem "where mycol is null".  Then you present a solution using two nested functions in the where clause, even while saying this should be avoided.  Only then do you get to the real solution.  In the future, present your real solution first.

Comment: What if I want to check if any of the column has a blank value. Let's say my table has 50 columns. Now check for each column one by one is time taking.

Answer (score 20):

Another method without WHERE, try this..

Will select both Empty and NULL values

```
SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF(fieldname,''))  FROM tablename
```

Comment: this returns 1 if there is something null, why is that so?

Comment: the NULLIF checks fieldname for the empty value and would convert to NULL if it was empty. The ISNULL returns 1 (true) if the NULLIF succesfully changed an empty field to NULL or if it was already NULL....    try for your self on a null and empty field in a  table with the two functions seperated   select isnull (X) , select nullif(y)

Answer (score 11):

Either

```
SELECT IF(field1 IS NULL or field1 = '', 'empty', field1) as field1 from tablename
```

or

```
SELECT case when field1 IS NULL or field1 = ''
        then 'empty'
        else field1
   end as field1 from tablename
```

Answer (score 8):

This statement is much cleaner and more readable for me:

```
select * from my_table where ISNULL(NULLIF(some_col, ''));
```

Answer (score 6):

try

```
SELECT 0 IS NULL ,  '' IS NULL , NULL IS NULL

-> 0, 0, 1
```

or

```
SELECT ISNULL('  ') , ISNULL( NULL )
 -> 0 ,1
```

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-null)

Answer (score 6):

I hate messy fields in my databases. If the column might be a blank string or null, I'd rather fix this before doing the select each time, like this:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET MyColumn=NULL WHERE MyColumn='';
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn IS NULL
```

This keeps the data tidy, as long as you don't specifically need to differentiate between NULL and empty for some reason.

Comment: That's interesting as a one-time fix. Or an occasional maintenance operation. But it wouldn't be practical while a database was in active use - UPDATE has to LOCK the table (for consistency). That would degrage PERFORMANCE if anyone else needs to access the same table. And then there is no guarantee that someone else wouldn't create a record that had a blank in it immediately after UPDATE finishes. This is a slippery slope.

Answer (score 6):

My two cents.

In MySQL you can use the [`COALESCE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function:

> Returns the first non-NULL value in the list, or NULL if there are no non-NULL values.

So you can simplify your query like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE COALESCE(some_col, '') = '';
```

Answer (score 5):

While checking `null or Empty` value for a column in my project, I noticed that there are some support concern in various Databases.

*Every Database doesn't support* `TRIM` *method.*

Below is the matrix just to understand the supported methods by different databases.

The TRIM function in SQL is used to remove specified prefix or suffix from a string. The most common pattern being removed is white spaces. This function is called differently in different databases:

- **MySQL:** `TRIM(), RTRIM(), LTRIM()`
- **Oracle:** `RTRIM(), LTRIM()`
- **SQL Server:** `RTRIM(), LTRIM()`

***How to Check Empty/Null :-***

> Below are two different ways according to different Databases-

The syntax for these trim functions are:

1. **Use of Trim to check-**

   `SELECT FirstName FROM UserDetails WHERE TRIM(LastName) IS NULL`
2. **Use of LTRIM & RTRIM to check-**

   `SELECT FirstName FROM UserDetails WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(LastName)) IS NULL`

*Above both ways provide same result just use based on your DataBase support. It Just returns the `FirstName` from `UserDetails` table if it has an empty `LastName`*

**Hoping this will help you :)**

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE trim(IFNULL(col,'')) <> '';
```

Comment: I had an issue comparing to a field that was sometimes null. This helped: `col1 != IFNULL(col2,'')`

Comment: FWIW: Its impossible for a string to be *less than* an empty string, so instead of `<>` can use `>`.

Comment: I found that using TRIM uses more resources (takes more time) than just <> '' etc. 
Not using it if not necessary though it's working, of course.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have NULL values presented last when doing an ORDER BY, try this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE NULLIF(some_col, '') IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also do

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_name LIKE ''
```

The inverse being

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_name NOT LIKE ''
```

Comment: Apparently does not work: `select NULL like ''` returns `NULL` - at least in MySQL.

Comment: PERFORMANCE: Don't use `LIKE` for an expression that can be done without it.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table where length(RTRIM(LTRIM(column_name))) > 0
```

Comment: What's the point in using both `RTRIM` and `LTRIM`, but not `TRIM`?

Comment: I find it interesting, but not recommendable ;) - uses up too many resources/time.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, space was entered in the column during the data import and though it looked like an empty column its length was 1. So first of all I checked the length of the empty looking column using `length(column)` then based on this we can write search query

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE LENGTH(column)=0;`

Comment: Huh? I don't understand what that code snippet says. Are you trying to say `LENGTH(column)=0`?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, did you know you have a high enough reputation to be able to edit answers to fix obvious spelling errors?

Comment: @pbarney - look at edit history, and see what the code looked like at the time I wrote my comment: `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE LENGHT(COLUMN)= length of column for empty column`. Then you'll see that Mr And edited the answer, in response to my comment. (If I had noticed he had edited answer, I would have removed my comment. This entire comment chain is now moot; I will ask moderator to remove it soon.)

Answer (score 0):

The below SQL query works fine.

```
SELECT * FROM <table-name> WHERE <column-name> IS NULL;
```

Comment: This won't return rows where column-name contains a blank ("").

Answer (score 0):

Below code works great, to check `null or empty` and `fallback` to other column:

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(col1, ''), col2) as 'someName'
```

Above sql means:

```
if `col1` column value is NOT null and NOT empty string  
then take `col1`
otherwise take `col2`  

return above value as `someName`
```

Answer (score -1):

Check for null

```
$column is null
isnull($column)
```

Check for empty

```
$column != ""
```

However, you should always set NOT NULL for column,
[mysql optimization can handle only one IS NULL level](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/is-null-optimization.html)

Comment: Never accepting `NULL` values is another whole topic for discussion. I don't think it's appropriate to make that recommendation without providing your reasoning.

Comment: I did include, be patient. Plus is really make life difficult using NULL (just like this question).

Comment: That's a terrible recommendation. Setting NOT NULL on a column whose value may not be known at the time of INSERT only serves to encourage the use of non-standard "null" values like `-1` and `''`.

Comment: @Dan if you aren't sure what are the value during insertion, you may have difficulties to conduct any possilbe optimization

Answer (score -1):

try this if the datatype are string and row is null

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_name IS NULL OR column_name = ''
```

if the datatype are int or column are 0 then try this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_name > = 0
```

Answer (score -1):

Get rows with NULL, 0, '', ' ', '     '

```
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE some_col IS NOT TRUE;
```

Get rows without NULL, 0, '', ' ', '     '

```
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE some_col IS TRUE;
```

Comment: I don't think this will work. `SELECT 'abc' <> '', 'abc' IS TRUE;` returns `1` and `0`.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE column_name IN (NULL, '')
```

Comment: Wrong answer. This won't select `NULL`.

Comment: To clarify @Pang's comment: Can't use NULL in an expression as if it were a value. You have to do special tests such as `... IS NULL` or `ISNULL(...)` Notice that code examples never say `column_name = NULL`. It just doesn't work that way.