# Include `WHERE` in a joined sql sequence

Tags: sql, where-clause

I have the following working sql sequence:

```
SELECT *, films.category AS filmCategory
FROM ( SELECT *
       FROM films
       ORDER BY `unique` ASC
       LIMIT 6, 4) films
LEFT OUTER JOIN items ON items.unique = films.ref
ORDER BY films.unique ASC
```

This works well and selects the correct four elements from the DB. However, I have some rules that I check for using `WHERE`, that I can't get working. I have done the following:

```
SELECT *, films.category AS filmCategory
FROM ( SELECT *
       FROM films
       ORDER BY `unique` ASC
       LIMIT 6, 4) films
LEFT OUTER JOIN items ON items.unique = films.ref
WHERE films.youtube IS NOT NULL AND films.youtube <> ''
ORDER BY films.unique ASC
```

where the only difference is the added line with the `WHERE` clause. But this doesn't work - in fact it makes no difference from before but returns the same rows.

How can I include these `WHERE` rules correctly in this sql sentence?

**Note**

The line `films.youtube IS NOT NULL AND films.youtube <> ''` is checking if a specific cell is empty. This is made with help from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470813/how-do-i-check-if-a-column-is-empty-or-null-in-mysql)

Comment: In what way is it not working?  Does it return rows that have NULL or "empty" values of `films.youtube`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for a `where` clause in the subquery?  That way, the `limit` will be applied **after** your `where` clause.

```
SELECT *, films.category AS filmCategory
FROM ( SELECT *
       FROM films
       WHERE films.youtube IS NOT NULL AND films.youtube <> ''
       ORDER BY `unique` ASC
       LIMIT 6, 4) films
LEFT OUTER JOIN items ON items.unique = films.ref
ORDER BY films.unique ASC
```

A small additional suggestion.  You can simplify:

```
WHERE films.youtube IS NOT NULL AND films.youtube <> ''
```

to

```
WHERE films.youtube > ''
```

because `null > ''` is not true (but `unknown`.)  Or perhaps more readable:

```
WHERE length(films.youtube) > 0
```

Comment: Even simpler: `WHERE films.youtube > ''`