# How can I check user value null or not within mysql syntax?

Tags: php, mysql

If the user sends AGE value null then don't execute. How do I write properly in MySQL

`$result = mysqli_query("select * from ident where FirstName = '$first_name' && $age != '' && Age = $age")`;

Comment: Just clarify: are you worried the age column in your mySQL table will be NULL, or the PHP variable `$age` will be null?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check if a column is empty or null in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470813/how-do-i-check-if-a-column-is-empty-or-null-in-mysql)

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
    if(!empty($age)){
    //do sql operation
    }
```

You can also add constraints if you want only specific age groups.
example:if you want age group between 18 and 40

```
    if ($_POST["age"] < 18 || $_POST["age"] > 40){
     //print error message
    }
    else{
     //do sql operation
    }
```

Comment: I think he's asking about how to do it within a mySQL query.

Answer (score 0):

You weren't very clear in your question, so I'll provide for both PHP & mySQL:

**mySQL**

Use the `IS NOT NULL`. [Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html)

```
SELECT * FROM ident 
    WHERE FirstName = '$first_name' 
    AND Age IS NOT NULL 
    AND Age = $age
```

**PHP**

Use `empty()` or `isset()`. [Reference.](http://sg3.php.net/empty)

```
if(!empty($age)){
    //execute mySQL
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `ident`
WHERE
    FirstName = '$first_name'
    && Age != ''
    && Age = $age
    && Age IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($age !== null) {
$result = mysqli_query("select * from ident where FirstName = '$first_name' Age = $age");
//etc..
}
```

Comment: @user3181614 no worries.

Answer (score 0):

You should check this on PHP page before querying the database.

```
<?php
if(!empty($age)) {
    $result = mysqli_query("select * from ident where FirstName = '$first_name' AND Age = '$age'");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be done on query building side, you might want to throw an exception if certain values are not met as expected

**PHP**
Use `is_null()` method or as said by @Huey

```
if(isset($age) and !is_null($age) and intval($age) > 0){
    $result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM ident WHERE FirstName = '$first_name' AND Age = $age");
}
```