# Sending message back if table row has value

Tags: php, mysql

For example, have a query like this:

```
<?php
$sql  = "INSERT INTO oppgave    
    (username, besvarelse, modulid) 
    VALUES
    ('$username', '$besvarelse', '$modulid');
    ";

    mysql_query($sql, $tilkobling);
?>
```

How can I do this:

If `modulid` row is not empty, echo "you have sent this modul before";

Comment: have you tried using triggers ?

Comment: are you trying to check where that particular row already exists before inserting into the database?

Comment: to know if a field is empty or not refer to this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470813/how-do-i-check-if-a-column-is-empty-or-null-in-mysql

Comment: the row modul id contain values from 1-6. if a user try input a value who alredy exist i want the user to get the message back that it already exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$sql  = "INSERT INTO oppgave(username, besvarelse, modulid) 
         select '$username', '$besvarelse', '$modulid'
         from dual
         where not exists (select modulid from oppgave where modulid='$modulid')";

$result=mysql_query($sql, $tilkobling);
if(mysql_affected_rows()==0){
      echo "Failed to insert duplicate modulid";
}else{
      echo "inserted";
}
?>
```

In this SQL Query, it will allow insert only if `$modulid` isn't already exist in database table. Such situation you can also handle by applying `UNIQUE` constraint to table column (but remember, it allows `NULL` value at once)

Comment: I think this is what i need Log1c, but getting this :  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in

Comment: Did u forgot to close `?>` ?

Comment: I think you already have The "<?php" and the "?>" Tag. Remove those from Log1c's answer

Comment: i'll get the data inserted eveytime :(

Comment: i have set modulid row as unique, do the data is not overwrited

Comment: @user2879767, Can i know the reason why you un-accepted my answer? It was correct as per your requirement specified *in the question*.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do this, is by not allowing duplicates.
You can do this with your SQL QUERY.
Build your query by this:

```
 $sqlString ="INSERT INTO oppgave('" . $username . "', '" . $besvarelse . "', '" . $modulid . "')
    SELECT username, besvarelse, modulid
    FROM oppgave
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM oppgave
                      WHERE modulid IS NULL)";
```

Please check all names and tablenames first ;)
Hope this helps.
If this the answer, please mark as answer.

Comment: But i think this isn't real answer to the question, as OP wants to *insert rows only if modulid isn't already exist in table* but here **your query won't allow duplicate rows (instead of just one column)**. Isn't it?