# Select empty records from field

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get the records where "fulltext" is empty.

This is wha I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `j30_k2_items` WHERE 'fulltext'= ' '
SELECT * FROM `j30_k2_items` WHERE 'fulltext'= ''
SELECT * FROM `j30_k2_items` WHERE 'fulltext' IS NULL
```

They all return an empty query although there are lots of records that match the query.

Comment: Use back-ticks for column names, and single quotes for string literals,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TRIM` function:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `j30_k2_items` 
WHERE TRIM(`fulltext`)= '' OR `fulltext` IS NULL
```

to get records that contains only whitespaces or are `NULL`.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'fulltext)= '' OR fulltext IS NULL ORDER BY `j30_k2_items`.`fulltext` ASC LIMIT' at line 3

Comment: @NunoNogueira Try with backtick

Comment: `FULLTEXT` is a reserved word

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470813/how-do-i-check-if-a-column-is-empty-or-null-in-mysql check this

Comment: @fancyPants Can you elaborate?

Comment: Well, the answer is in the duplicate question. And it would be nice if you would rather make use of your reputation points to vote to close such questions than answering the same question for the hundredth time.