# When Then order of operations

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the correct order of operation in SQL for my case statement and every combination I try seems to be failing me.

When I run my simple statement of:

```
select CustomerName, AccountNumber, AccountID, VendorID, ClientID
from data
```

I yield results of:

```
CustomerName    AccountNumber   AccountID   VendorID    ClientID
Customer 1      3870465001                              38
Customer 2      5135550000                  48          58
Customer 3      8335 10 001     58          55          45
```

Here is what I'm currently trying:

```
select CustomerName, AccountNumber, 
  case  
    when AccountID = '' then VendorID
    when AccountID = '' and VendorID = '' then ClientID
    else AccountID 
  end as EffectiveID
from data
```

and hoping to see:

```
CustomerName    AccountNumber   EffectiveID 
Customer 1      3870465001      38
Customer 2      5135550000      48          
Customer 3      8335 10 001     58
```

but I only end with the result for Customer 2

Comment: Switch the order of the first 2 branches of CASE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second statement in case will never execute, so you have to switch it with first

```
SELECT CustomerName, AccountNumber, 
  CASE  
    WHEN AccountID = '' AND VendorID = '' THEN ClientID
    WHEN AccountID = '' THEN VendorID
    ELSE AccountID 
  END AS EffectiveID
FROM data
```

If you have to check null as well as empty you have to modify it as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8470865/297087)

```
WHEN (AccountID IS NULL OR AccountID = '') AND (VendorID IS NULL OR VendorID = '') THEN ClientID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select CustomerName, AccountNumber, 
  case  
    when AccountID != '' then AccountID
    when VendorID != '' then VendorID
    else ClientId 
  end as EffectiveID
from data
```

Comment: I think it will not work as expected when `VendorID` is empty & AccountID, ClientID are not empty.

Comment: @Salil CASE WHEN follows the order of execution with the earliest first. If the first statement `VendorID = ''` is not satisfied it will go to the next statement. In short, it works like `if, else if, else` statement

Comment: Yeah, but when `VendorID ` is empty it will display `ClientID` even if `AccountID` is present.

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_