# How identify random spaces blank in field ActiveRecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I found myself performing a rake task to replace with `-` the first_name and last_name `nil` of the `Client` model, but later I was surprised that there was not only `nil` in both fields, but also `''` `' '` `'   '` and more, is there a way to identify the customers that meet all these conditions without having to go through all the `Clients`?

To clarify, previously the `Client` model did not have validation for these fields.

Comment: Try `Client.where.not("first_name > ''")` if this works for you

Comment: it works with some cases, for example the Client that I have with first_name: '     ' is not returned by this query, but it is an advance. thanks!

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470813/how-do-i-check-if-a-column-is-empty-or-null-in-mysql

Comment: `Client.where("NULLIF(TRIM(first_name),'') IS NULL")` should handle all of the above cases assuming that those are actually blank spaces and not unprintable characters like horizontal tab. You can then follow this with an `update_all` call to update all the records to meet your criteria if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @engineersmnky, your answer helped my solution.

for an update of attribute with the next cases:

- NULL
- ''
- '  '
- ' ' * n

the solution: `Model.where("NULLIF(TRIM(col),'') IS NULL")`